# Postfix not using "non_smptd_milters"

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, dkim, ubuntu-14.04, opendkim

Currently configuring a mail server using Postfix/Dovecot on Ubuntu 14.04 x86. At the moment I'm trying to setup DKIM using OpenDKIM. The guide I am following tells us to put the parameter `"non_smtpd_milters=inet:localhost:8891"` in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`. However, when I `service postfix restart` I get many warnings:

```
* Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent postfix      
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: non_smptd_milters=inet:localhost:8891
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: non_smptd_milters=inet:localhost:8891
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: non_smptd_milters=inet:localhost:8891
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: non_smptd_milters=inet:localhost:8891
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: non_smptd_milters=inet:localhost:8891
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: non_smptd_milters=inet:localhost:8891
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: non_smptd_milters=inet:localhost:8891
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: non_smptd_milters=inet:localhost:8891
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: non_smptd_milters=inet:localhost:8891
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: non_smptd_milters=inet:localhost:8891
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: non_smptd_milters=inet:localhost:8891
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: non_smptd_milters=inet:localhost:8891
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: non_smptd_milters=inet:localhost:8891
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: non_smptd_milters=inet:localhost:8891
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: non_smptd_milters=inet:localhost:8891
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: non_smptd_milters=inet:localhost:8891
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: non_smptd_milters=inet:localhost:8891
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: non_smptd_milters=inet:localhost:8891
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: non_smptd_milters=inet:localhost:8891
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: non_smptd_milters=inet:localhost:8891
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: non_smptd_milters=inet:localhost:8891
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: non_smptd_milters=inet:localhost:8891
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

A copy of my `main.cf` can be found here: http://pastebin.com/mLnUdFHS

Comment: *non_smptd_milters!=non_smtpd_milters*  See [the documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#non_smtpd_milters)

Comment: @masegaloeh Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, I'm not sure I understand. Those two parameters look the same to me, and the documentation doesn't make it any clearer to me :( Sorry! Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: Documentation says s m *t p* d. Your config says s m *p t* d.

Comment: Ahhhhhhh..... I am truly blind. Thank you SO much. I've seen too many ss, ms, ts and ps today...

Comment: Posted it in answers section. Please consider to [accepting it](http://serverfault.com/help/someone-answers) so this question doesn't float in [unanswered pool](http://serverfault.com/unanswered).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misspelled parameter [non_smtpd_milters](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#non_smtpd_milters). Your config says *non_sm**pt**d_milters* not *non_sm**tp**d_milters*.

<sub>**How I spot it:** Googling for [keyword non_smptd_milters](https://www.google.com/search?q=non_smptd_milters) would yield 5 results, but for [keyword non_smtpd_milters](https://www.google.com/search?q=non_smtpd_milters) would yield thousands result.</sub>